# Screensaver doesn't install in other machines Preferences Pane

Tags: xcode, macos, screensaver

I am writing a simple screensaver app. I run *Product > Archive* from Xcode, *Distribute*, *Save built products* and I get the *.saver* file. I then can install it with no problem on my development machine, while on other machines (64 bit, 10.7 as well) it doesn't install it.

Actually if I move the .saver file inside /Users/user/Library/Screen Savers/ and go to Preferences Pane, it complains saying: "You can't use this screensaver on this computer. Contact the developer for an up-to-date version."

Answer (score 0):

I have been experimenting with writing a screensaver and get this warning scrolling in the screensaver preview panel if I use depreciated code - I usually find that looking into the Objective C reference there are suggestions of replacements to use

e.g. These are both declared in `NSString.h`

```
+ (id)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url NS_DEPRECATED(10_0, 10_4, 2_0, 2_0);
```

causes the warning

```
+ (id)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error;
```

doesn't

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click for menu then select jump to definition and then highlight and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click to get suggested replacements